# Disabling drop for images within the droppable

Tags: jquery-ui

I have an image that I drag from one part of the page and drop into a DIV.  No problem. But when I just drag the image around inside its new DIV home, I still trigger the DIV's drop handler. Is there an easy way to disable the drop handler for elements that are already in the droppable?

Thanks

Comment: provide some code, you tried

Comment: I can imaging requiring an extra class to be eligible to for dropping and then removing that class once dropped.  But the UI code must know when an element being dropped is already in the droppable (I'm surprised the drop handler even gets called in that case) so I'm thinking that there must be a clever way to disable drops in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the dropped element, then in the drop function check if the element have that and if so exit the drop function.

In my example I clone the element in a new one on drop, if you use the dragged you must change the selected element.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".doodad").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        scroll: true
    });

    $(".dropped").draggable({
        containment: ".box"
    });
    $(".box").droppable({
        accept: ".doodad",
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('copied')) return
            alert('dropped');
            var droppedItem = $(ui.draggable).clone().addClass('copied').css({
                position: "relative",
                top: $(ui.helper).position().top - $(this).position().top,
                left: $(ui.helper).position().left - $(this).position().left
            }).draggable({
                containment: ".box"
            });
            $(this).append(droppedItem);

        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/hLxAd/